# handler.ServeHTTP(w,req) and handler(w,req) difference in tests

Tags: http, go, testing, go-testing

I'm trying to understand the difference between `handler.ServeHTTP(w,req)` and `handler(w,req)` in Go testing. When should I use each of them? Are they exactly the same?

Docs say simply: `ServeHTTP calls f(w, r).`

```
for _, tt := range tests {
    t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
        request := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/status", nil)
        w := httptest.NewRecorder()
        h := http.HandlerFunc(handlers.StatusHandler)
      
        h.ServeHTTP(w, request)
        /// or should it be
        h(w, request)
        
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the two calls are the same. That's what the documentation says, and you can just look at the implementation: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.4:src/net/http/server.go;l=2108

Comment: They are the same, use whichever you like best.

Answer (score 1):

As [@peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603316/peter) and [@mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva) pointed out, the options are exactly the same and it's a matter of taste